# Text extracted from iText not properly rendered

Tags: java, pdf, java-8, itext

I have extracted text from iText. And created a list of characters along with there location. This is the code for creating textInfoList with line locations.

```
@Override
void eventOccurred(IEventData data, EventType type) {
    if (type== EventType.RENDER_TEXT) {
        TextRenderInfo renderInfo = (TextRenderInfo) data
        textInfoItems.addAll(TextInfoFactory.createTextInfoList(renderInfo))
    }
}

    static List<TextInfo> createTextInfoList(TextRenderInfo renderInfo) {
    List<TextInfo> infoList = new ArrayList<>()
    String text
    PdfFont font = renderInfo.getFont()
    FontProgram fontProgram = font?.getFontProgram()
    FontNames fontNames = fontProgram?.getFontNames()
    String fontName = fontNames?.getFontName()
    PdfString pdfString = renderInfo.getPdfString()
    String rawValue = pdfString?.getValue()
    // Get actual font size for rendered text
    float textFontSize = getFontSize(renderInfo)

    if (pdfString && !StringUtils.isEmpty(rawValue)) {

        if (!fontName) {
            // Work around for bad fonts
            text = rawValue.replaceAll('\u009C', '*').replaceAll('\\p{C}\\s*', ' ')
        } else {
            // Sometimes the symbol font isn't loaded properly
            if (fontName?.contains("Symbol")) {
                try {
                    font = PdfFontFactory.createFont("Symbol")
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
            GlyphLine gl = font.decodeIntoGlyphLine(pdfString)
            // Our custom unicode conversion adjusts for fonts that are missing unicode map.

            final char REPLACEMENT_CHARACTER = '\ufffd'
            ActualTextIterator iterator = new ActualTextIterator(gl, gl.start, gl.end)
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder()
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                GlyphLine.GlyphLinePart part = iterator?.next()
                if (part.actualText != null) {
                    str.append(part.actualText)
                } else {
                    for (int i = part.start; i < part.end; i++) {
                        if (gl.get(i)) {
                            // This is our custom fix for bad characters in font
                            // If we can't use font value, then just get char value from the raw string.
                            char[] unicodeChars = gl.get(i).getUnicodeChars()
                            for (int j = 0; j < unicodeChars.length; ++j) {
                                // iText uses arbitrary replacement logic, we  need something better.
                                // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullet_(typography)#In_Unicode
                                String value = getCharacterForUnicode(fontName, unicodeChars[j])
                                if (value) {
                                    str.append(value)
                                } else if (unicodeChars[j].equals(REPLACEMENT_CHARACTER)) {
                                    char charAtIndex = rawValue.charAt(j + i)
                                    str.append((charAtIndex != '\t') ? charAtIndex : ' ')
                                } else {
                                    str.append(unicodeChars[j])
                                }
                            }
                        } else if (rawValue.length() > 0 && i < rawValue.length()) {
                            // replace funky chars
                            str.append(rawValue.replaceAll('\u009C', '*').replaceAll('\\p{C}', ' ').charAt(i))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            text = str.toString().replaceAll('[^\\u0009\\u000a\\u000d\\u0020-\\uD7FF\\uE000-\\uFFFD]|\t', '')
        }

        if (text.length() == 1) {
            // USE CASE 1
            // This is a very common use case
            infoList.add(
                    new TextInfo(
                            text,
                            new TextInfoLocation(
                                    renderInfo.ascentLine,
                                    renderInfo.baseline,
                                    renderInfo.descentLine,
                                    renderInfo.rise,
                                    renderInfo.singleSpaceWidth),
                            renderInfo.getFont(),
                            textFontSize,
                            renderInfo.getStrokeColor()))
        } else if (text.length() <= renderInfo.characterRenderInfos.size()) {
            // USE CASE 2
            // This is the other normal use case. We have all of the render information for each character in a longer string
            // If there is more than enough character render info, we assume the ones at the end are not needed.
            text.eachWithIndex { String entry, int i ->
                TextRenderInfo charInfo = renderInfo.characterRenderInfos[i]
                infoList.add(
                        new TextInfo(
                                entry,
                                new TextInfoLocation(
                                        charInfo.ascentLine,
                                        charInfo.baseline,
                                        charInfo.descentLine,
                                        charInfo.rise,
                                        charInfo.singleSpaceWidth),
                                renderInfo.getFont(),
                                textFontSize,
                                renderInfo.getStrokeColor()))
            }
            if (text.length() < renderInfo.characterRenderInfos.size()) {
                // DEV NOTE: If the characterRenderInfos are actually incorrect or off a bit, consider also using the logic in the else-if below as a potential solution.
                // Such a condition has not been fully researched.
                log.trace("RARE CONDITION (Text USE CASE 2): More character information than actual text. Confirm text positions are correct.")
            }
        } else if (text.length() > renderInfo.characterRenderInfos.size()) {
            // USE CASE 3
            // We have more text than render information. This situation shouldn't happen, but it can in poorly created PDFs.
            log.trace("RARE CONDITION (Text USE CASE 3): More text than actual character info. Confirm text positions are correct.")
            // Take the full length of the render info and slice it up evenly by the number of characters.
            // This algorithm works regardless of rotation
            float ascentLineStartX = renderInfo.ascentLine.startPoint.get(I1)
            float ascentLineStartY = renderInfo.ascentLine.startPoint.get(I2)

            float baselineStartX = renderInfo.baseline.startPoint.get(I1)
            float baselineStartY = renderInfo.baseline.startPoint.get(I2)
            float baselineEndX = renderInfo.baseline.endPoint.get(I1)
            float baselineEndY = renderInfo.baseline.endPoint.get(I2)

            float descentLineStartX = renderInfo.descentLine.startPoint.get(I1)
            float descentLineStartY = renderInfo.descentLine.startPoint.get(I2)

            // Assume diff is the same for all 3 line segments
            float xDiff = (float) ((baselineEndX - baselineStartX) / text.length())
            float yDiff = (float) ((baselineEndY - baselineStartY) / text.length())

            text.eachWithIndex { String entry, int i ->
                Vector startVector = new Vector(ascentLineStartX, ascentLineStartY, 1f)
                ascentLineStartX += xDiff
                ascentLineStartY += yDiff
                Vector endVector = new Vector(ascentLineStartX, ascentLineStartY, 1f)
                LineSegment ascentLine = new LineSegment(startVector, endVector)

                startVector = new Vector(baselineStartX, baselineStartY, 1f)
                baselineStartX += xDiff
                baselineStartY += yDiff
                endVector = new Vector(baselineStartX, baselineStartY, 1f)
                LineSegment baseline = new LineSegment(startVector, endVector)

                startVector = new Vector(descentLineStartX, descentLineStartY, 1f)
                descentLineStartX += xDiff
                descentLineStartY += yDiff
                endVector = new Vector(descentLineStartX, descentLineStartY, 1f)
                LineSegment descentLine = new LineSegment(startVector, endVector)

                infoList.add(
                        new TextInfo(
                                entry,
                                new TextInfoLocation(
                                        ascentLine,
                                        baseline,
                                        descentLine,
                                        renderInfo.rise,
                                        renderInfo.singleSpaceWidth),
                                renderInfo.getFont(),
                                textFontSize,
                                renderInfo.getStrokeColor()))
            }
        }
    }
    return infoList
}
```

This is stream of text from iText.

```
-0.606 -1.121 Td
( ) Tj
0.006 Tc
0.606 0 Td
(Data Set Location: h) Tj
(ome/lillyce/prd/ly2148568/h8o_mc_gwde/final/data/shared/ads                                                     ) Tj
0 Tc
( ) Tj
EMC
/P <</MCID 41 >> BDC
/F2 1 Tf
12 0 0 12 72 103.44 Tm
<0003> Tj
/F1 1 Tf
7.92 0 0 7.92 216 103.44 Tm
( ) Tj
```

After the line "Data Set Location: home/lillyce/prd/ly2148568/h8o_mc_gwde/final/data/shared/ads      ". There are some weird characters which I don't understand.
Those weird characters are added to the line something like this.
"  Data Set Location: home/lillyc e/prd/ly2148568/h8o_mc_gwde/final/data/shared/ads      "
Just before "D" one space is added and after "c" in "lillyce" one space is added.

```
I am sorting them based on there location.
This is the code for checking each character location for same line or different line.

boolean isOnTheSameLine(PdfLocation otherLocation) {
        // Angular magnitudes must be the same to be considered on the same line.
        if (angularMagnitude != otherLocation.angularMagnitude) {
            return false
        }

        // Completely different lines
        if (distPerpendicularEnd < otherLocation.distPerpendicularStart || distPerpendicularStart > otherLocation.distPerpendicularEnd) {
            return false
        }

        // Start perpendicular edges are VERY close (also handles some sub/superscript)
        float distTopStartDiff = (float) Math.abs(distPerpendicularStart - otherLocation.distPerpendicularStart)
        if (distTopStartDiff < FLOAT_EPSILON) {
            return true
        }

        // End perpendicular edges are VERY close (also handles some sub/superscript)
        float distTopEndDiff = (float) Math.abs(distPerpendicularEnd - otherLocation.distPerpendicularEnd)
        if (distTopEndDiff < FLOAT_EPSILON) {
            return true
        }

        // Subscript and superscript detection
        if (isOnTheSameLinePartially(otherLocation)) {
            return true
        }

        // RARE USE CASE: Some kind of condition inherited from iText -- Serves a purpose in some weird circumstance when no width is present.
        return distTopStartDiff <= DIACRITICAL_MARKS_ALLOWED_VERTICAL_DEVIATION && (distParallelStart == distParallelEnd || otherLocation.distParallelStart == otherLocation.distParallelEnd)
    }
```

So while checking each character for same line.

0 Tc
( ) Tj
EMC
/P <</MCID 41 >> BDC
/F2 1 Tf
12 0 0 12 72 103.44 Tm
<0003> Tj
/F1 1 Tf
7.92 0 0 7.92 216 103.44 Tm
( ) Tj

Somehow these two weird characters are considered in same line as
"Data Set Location: home/lillyce/prd/ly2148568/h8o_mc_gwde/final/data/shared/ads      "

Comment: I don't really understand, which two extra space characters are added where? And how do you extract text to start with? You show two methods, but how are they used in your approach?

Comment: @mkl I have made few changes to the question. Please have a look and let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are surprised about two space characters, one before the "D", one after the "c". But at least the space right in front of the "D" clearly is drawn by the `( ) Tj` at the start of your content stream excerpt. To identify the instruction drawing the space after the "c", though, your excerpt is to small.